# Canoncial or 301 redirect for two URL showing one page

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, http-status-code-301, canonical-link

I have HTML page http://www.example.com/report.html and how can I make that also url http://www.example.com/publactions.html is showing same page without getting duplicate content?

Should I use canonical link or 301 redirect in .htaccess (what is most correct practice)?

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, you should implement canonical URLs on all pages that will be indexed by a search engine.  You'll want to do this no matter what.

In regards to duplicate content, the goal is always to eliminate it and host the content in a single location.  I would recommend selecting one location to host the content and then setting up the other as a 301 redirect to the canonical location.